# Basic set of programming steps to be programmed to trigger an LPI in ARMv8A in a bare-metal environment?

Tags: interrupt, arm64, armv8

I recently brought up Locality-Specific Interrupts (LPI) in a bare-metal software environment on an ARMv8A core. LPIs specifically require a relatively larger set of steps to be performed and it is a little difficult to get a higher level view of all the required steps from the specifications alone. I was not able to obtain a single-point reference for all the steps needed mentioned in order, anywhere online to the extent that I searched. Hence I am asking this question and answering it with my own answer for the same - obtained through the experience of my own bringup of LPIs.

Answer (score 1):

In this post, my aim is to provide a concise high-level one-place description of the programming required to trigger an LPI (Locality-Specific Interrupt) on a bare-metal ARM v8A validation framework.

The ARM architecture defines a special component called the Generic Interrupt Controller (GIC) which is responsible for managing all the interrupts defined in the architecture. There are 4 kinds of interrupts defined - SGI (Software Generated Interrupts), PPI (Private Peripheral Interrupt), SPI (Shared Peripheral Interrupt) and LPI (Locality-Specific Interrupt).

From the ARM/GIC specifications, we can see that the programming required to generate LPIs on a bare-metal framework is considerably more than the programming required for the other 3 types.

This post is not intended to be standalone guide to triggering LPIs. It can ideally be used to form a clear high-level picture of the programming needed after having gone once through LPI related sections of the GIC specification.

LPIs are also supported on all implementations of Linux for ARM. If a booted OS is available, an even higher-level approach to programming LPIs can be taken (using Linux capabilities) and the task becomes easier. However, on most bare-metal frameworks, we would be needed to perform all the required programming ourselves and thats where I hope that the set of steps below will help reach the goal to enabling LPIs faster.

Note - The GIC components (distributor, redistributors, GITS) are memory mapped components. All the settings mentioned below would take the form of loads and stores. The SoC documentation should be able to provide the information of where these components are located in the memory map.

I suggest reading the ARM and GIC specifications to understand all the deeper implications of the register fields accessed in the steps below.

Basics

An LPI is typically triggered by one of the devices in a SoC and targetted to one of the CPUs in the system.
Each device may need to trigger interrupts of different types of target different cores for the different types of services that it may need.
Hence an LPI is identified by a tuple - (DeviceID, EventID).
There are a large number of LPIs supported in the architecture (8192 to 2^16-1 or event 2^24-1). Typically, large sets of LPI interrupts may be serviceable from the same CPU.
Hence a concept called Interrupt Collection ID (ICID) is introduced. This refers to a set of LPIs which are to be sent to the same CPU.
Data structures

Before going into the programming, let us take a look at all the data structures required to set up LPIs and the interaction between them.

There are six (6) data structures required to set up LPIs -

a. LPI properties table

contains information about the interrupt priority and enable bit for each of the LPIs - one byte for each LPI.
the first 8192 bytes do not exist in this table
Pointed to by GICR_PROPBASER
Please read the GIC specification to understand the meanings of the fields in this register
b. LPI pending table

contains information about the pending state of each of the LPIs - one byte for each LPI
the first 8192 bytes are IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED in this table and the LPI pending bit statuses are placed after this memory block
Pointed to by GICR_PENDBASER
Please read the GIC specification to understand the meanings of the fields in this register
c. ITS command queue

contains the sequence of commands to be executed by the ITS (Interrupt Translation Service)
It is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED whether a GIC implementation allows triggering of LPIs without using the ITS or not
Registers GICR_SETLPIR and GICR_CLRLPIR are implemented in this case
Please read the GIC specification to understand more details 
If the ITS is to be used to trigger LPIs, we need to create a sequence of commands that are understood specifically by the ITS.
The base of the queue of commands in memory is pointed to by GITS_CBASER
The current command being read by the ITS for execution is pointed to by GITS_CREADR
The last command in the queue is pointed to by GITS_CWRITER.
d. Device table

This table stores the mapping from a given DeviceID to an Interrupt Translation Table for that device.
e. Interrupt Translation Table

The interrupt translation table stores the mapping from a given EventID to the corresponding physical interrupt ID (which interrupt number to present to the core) and the ICID (looked up further to obtain the destination CPU)

f. Collection Table

This table stores the mapping from a given ICID to the target redistributor to which the physical interrupt ID is sent.
Lookup flow

The lookup flow (4 lookups and 1 table set) for an LPI is placed in brief below -

a. LPI triggered with a combination of (Device ID, Event ID)

b. Device ID is looked up in the Devices table to obtain the corresponding Interrupt Translation Table (ITT)

c. Event ID is looked up in the ITT to obtain the physical interrupt ID to be triggered and the interrupt collection ID (ICID)

d. The ICID is further looked up in the collection table to obtain the target redistributor

e. The LPI properties table is looked up to check whether the LPI is enabled

If the LPI is enabled, the LPI pending table is updated so that the physical interrupt is put in pending state.

When the core enters the appropriate state(exception level, priority etc.) the pending LPI is "taken" by the core.

Programming Steps

Now onto the actual programming steps (7 steps) -

1. Enable GIC in the system.

a. Enable Nonsecure Group 1 interrupts in the distributor.

GICD_CTLR.EnableGrp1NS = 1
LPI interrupts are always Nonsecure Group 1 interrupts

b. Bring the redistributor out of sleep.

There is an architectural and an IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED part to this.
Architectural part - Set GICR_WAKER.ProcessorSleep to 0 and wait till GICR_WAKER.ChildrenAsleep = 0.
IMP DEF part - this is different for different GIC implementation. For example - for a GIC-600 implementation, there is a register called GICR_PWRR, and setting GICR_PWRR.RDPD and GICR_PWRR.RDAG to 0 is required before writing GICR_WAKER as per the above step.
The SoC documentation should be able to provide the required steps here

2. Zero-initialize a block of memory which will be used by all tables used for LPIs
3. Allocate memories for LPI property table, LPI pending table and the ITS command queue

In many bare-metal framework, "allocating" may just be deciding offline which address ranges to use and making sure that the above tables are placed in distinct regions in memory
Set GICR_PROPBASER to point to a suitable memory region (64kB aligned is preferred)
Set GICR_PENDBASER to point to a suitable memory region (64kB aligned)
Set GICR_CBASER to point to a suitable memory region (64kB aligned)

4. Allocate memory for the Devices table and the Collections table

These tables are pointed to by the GITS_BASER registers
These registers need to be read first to understand which register points to which kind of table (GITS_BASER.Type field). This is fixed by the implementation.
Set the appropriate indices of the GITS_BASER to point to an empty Device table and Collection table

5. Enable LPIs for the redistributor

Set GICR_CTLR.EnableLPIs = 1

6. Create a command queue

The basic sequence needed to trigger an LPI is provided below - 
MAPD 
Creates a device table entry mapping DeviceID -> ITT table
MAPTI
Creates an ITT table entry mapping EventID -> (physical LPI ID (pINTID), ICID (Interrupt Collections ID))
MAPC
Creates a collection table entry mapping ICID -> Redistributor address
There are two possible formats of the redistributor address - physical address or Processor Num
GITS_TYPER.PTA indicates which format is to be used
GICR_TYPER.ProcessorNumber indicates the processor number assigned to the redistributor
INT
"Software" triggering of LPI - this instruction takes a DeviceID and EventID, takes them through the ITS translation and requests the target redistributor to set the appropriate LPI pending table bit.

7. Enable the ITS

Set GITS_TYPER.Enable = 1. 
This will start the execution of the ITS commands in the command queue, and if everything is set up correctly, should lead to the LPI changing to pending state at the redistributor associated with the target core.

Thank you for reading this post and I really hope that it helps in getting to triggering LPIs on a bare-metal system faster.

Please let me know in comments if you would like any more information to be added or if there are any corrections to be made.

Thanks!!!